# jQuery to clone row of table

Tags: jquery, radio-button, clone, rows

I am using jQuery to clone the first table I have and adding rows to my second table. The problem I am having is that I can't get the value of the radio button when one is selected and the add button is clicked. Also when I click the add button I am trying to replace it with a checkbox but it is only working the middle rows and not the last row I add when I click on add.

How can I get the values for the radio buttons and replace the add button on the cloned row with a checkbox?

This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/AkVTw/42/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to **delegate the event** as the Newly added element would not have the click event  handler associated with it as the Element was non existent on the page when you bind the event handler..

Replace this line of code

```
$('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
```

With this

```
$('table').on('click','.checkbox', function(){
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/AkVTw/49/)**

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AkVTw/51/)

Comment: it doesn't do anything differently. The radio buttons are still all using the same selector and there is still an add button showing on the last cloned row

Comment: Check the updated fiddle.. Just remove the .checkbox from the cloned element .. http://jsfiddle.net/AkVTw/51/